# Fetch JSON array into fullcalenar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to add appointment from `MySQL` to `fullcalendar` but still can't. Here is my `PHP` code:

**EDIT**

```
(function ($) { 
                $(document).ready(function() {

                  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                      eventSources: [

                        // your event source
                        {
                            url: 'fullcalendar/get-events.php',
                            error: function() {
                                alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
                            },
                            color: 'yellow',   // a non-ajax option
                            textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
                        }

                        // any other sources...

                    ]
                });

              });
            })(jQuery);
```

-

```
//Include connection file
require_once('global.php');

//Json and PHP header
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$events = array();
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$id_logged = $_SESSION['login_id'];

    $search_date = "SELECT * FROM appointment INNER JOIN patient ON appointment.patient_id = patient.id WHERE appointment.id_logged = :id_logged";
    $search_date_stmt = $conn->prepare($search_date);
    $search_date_stmt->bindValue(':id_logged', $id_logged);
    $search_date_stmt->execute();
    $search_date_stmt_fetch = $search_date_stmt->fetchAll();

    foreach($search_date_stmt_fetch as $row)
    {
        $events[] = array(
       'title' => $row['patient_name'],
       'start'   => $row['date_app'],
       'end'    => $row['date_app']),
       'allDay' => false;
    }

    echo json_encode($events);
?>
```

And here is `fullcalendar` script:

```
    <script>
        (function ($) { 
            $(document).ready(function() {
              $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                  header: {
                      left: 'prev,next today',
                      center: 'title',
                      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                  },
                  editable: true,
                  eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                  events: {
                      url: 'fullcalendar/get-events.php',
                      //url: 'fullcalendar/myfeed.php',
                  },
                  loading: function(bool) {
                      $('#loading').toggle(bool);
                  }
              });

          });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

And here is the console result:

[image]

So I am getting data. But in the query string Parameters I have a start and end values that I don't know what they are and can't see anything inside my calendar.

[image]

I hope I can get some help. I was working on it since yesterday and can't get any result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, set the Calendar source to your PHP feed:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        theme: true,
        lang: 'es',            
        timezone: 'UTC',
        editable: true,
        selectable: true,
        events: '../calendar.php'
 });
```

The calendar will send a request like this:
http://localhost/calendar.php?start=2016-02-01&end=2016-03-14&_=1457633346896

Now full the PHP file:

```
<?php
header( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");  
header( 'Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT' ); 
header( 'Last-Modified: ' . gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s' ) . ' GMT' ); 
header( 'Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate' ); 
header( 'Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false ); 
header( 'Pragma: no-cache' ); 

date_default_timezone_set("UTC");    // Set the default timezone
$response = null;

if (isset($_GET["start"]) && isset($_GET["end"]) ) {   
    //--Esta es la consulta principal del calendario:
    $GLOBALS['response'] = GetCalendar($_GET["start"], $_GET["end"] ) ;
} 

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($GLOBALS['response'], true);//<- Response always in JSON format.
echo PHP_EOL;
//============================================================================
function GetCalendar($Start, $End) {
   //start=2016-02-29 end=2016-04-11           
   $response = null;
   $conn = null;

   try {
      $odbc_name = 'myODBCname';

      $sql_query = "SELECT id_event, tipo, descripcion, fecha_inicio, NVL(fecha_fin, MDY(1,1,1)) fecha_fin, 
                    NVL(back_color,'') back_color, NVL(text_color,'') text_color, id_usuario, desc_usuario
                    FROM webapps_calendar
                    WHERE fecha_inicio BETWEEN '".$Start."' AND '".$End."'
                    OR fecha_fin BETWEEN '".$Start."' AND '".$End."' 
                    ORDER BY 1;";

      $conn = odbc_connect($odbc_name, 'user', 'password');
      $result = odbc_exec($conn, $sql_query);
      $response = array();     

       if($result) {
            $response = array();
            while( $row = odbc_fetch_array($result) ) { 
                if ($row['tipo'] == 'evento') {
                    //--Aqui van los Eventos normales ingresados por los usuarios --*/
                    $json['id'] = $row['id_event'];
                    $json['title'] = utf8_encode($row['descripcion']);    
                    $json['start'] = (new DateTime($row['fecha_inicio']))->modify("+12 hours")->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');                        
                    $json['end'] = (new DateTime($row['fecha_fin']))->modify("+12 hours")->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                    $json['allDay'] = false;
                    $json['timezone'] = 'UTC';

                    if($row['back_color'] != ''){ $json['color'] = $row['back_color']; } else { $json['color'] = null; }               
                    if($row['text_color'] != ''){ $json['textColor'] = $row['text_color']; } else { $json['textColor'] = null; }    

                    $json['usuario'] = $row['desc_usuario'];
                    $json['user_id'] = $row['id_usuario'];
                    $json['overlap'] = null;
                    $json['rendering'] = null; 
                    $json['type'] = 'Evento';

                    array_push($response, $json); 

                } else {
                    //-- Este es un Dia Feriado -*/
                    $json['id'] = $row['id_event'];
                    $json['title'] = utf8_encode($row['descripcion']);

                    $json['start'] = (new DateTime($row['fecha_inicio']))->modify("+12 hours")->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                    if($row['fecha_fin'] != '0001-01-01') {                        
                        $json['end'] = (new DateTime($row['fecha_fin']))->modify("+12 hours")->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                    } else { 
                        $json['end'] = null; 
                    } 
                    $json['allDay'] = true;

                    $json['color'] = '#ff9f89';
                    $json['textColor'] = null;
                    $json['rendering'] = 'background';   
                    $json['overlap'] = true;
                    $json['type'] = 'Feriado';

                    array_push($response, $json); 
                }          

            }  

            //Libera recursos y cierra la conexion
            odbc_free_result($result);
        }

   } catch (Exception $e) {
       $response = array('resultado' => 'err', 'detalle' => $e->getMessage());
       echo 'ERROR: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
   }
   odbc_close($conn);
   return $response;
}
?>
```

That PHP feed will query the database using an ODBC conection and return both regular events and national festivities, i also added a couple of custom properties to each event.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the method eventSources instead of events, sample:

```
 eventSources: [

    // your event source
    {
        url: '/myfeed.php', // use the `url` property
        color: 'yellow',    // an option!
        textColor: 'black'  // an option!
    }

    // any other sources...

]
```

More info: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/

Comment: Yes, it should work. Beware the "/" start the path to that file must be absolute from the root.

Comment: see my edit please. I can see the same data inside network XHR, but still not on the calendar, no errors at console

Comment: any more help ? I am really stressed now because of it.

Comment: `appointments.php:88 Uncaught ReferenceError: title is not defined`

Comment: was my example, not with your data ;)

Try:
 $events[] = array(
       'title' => $row['patient_name'],
       'start'   =>  date('Y-m-d',$row['date_app']),
       'end'    => date('Y-m-d',$row['date_app']),
       'allDay' => false);

Comment: nope, nothing worked. I am thinking literally of kicking my laptop out of the window

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is problem of constructing the array of events

My sample:

```
$a_event = array();
$a_event['title'] = $title;
$a_event['url'] = $href;
$a_event['start'] = date('Y-m-d',$date_start);
array_push($a_events_json, $a_event);
```

In your capture, json seems not right, I do not see either the "start" field

maybe your problem is in this line.

```
start'   => $row['date_app'],
```